# PHP How to output the array content

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

A function returns array of following type:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [post_id] => 48
```

I want to echo the array contents, so i tried using following foreach loop:

```
foreach ($posts as $post){
    echo $post['post_id'];
}
```

But I get following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: The error message is quite clear: *"Cannot use **object** [...] as **array** [...]"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array of objects. So, you need to change:

```
echo $post['post_id'];
```

To:

```
echo $post->post_id;
```

Now, you're printing the object property `post_id`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to output array or object information for something like debugging, you can do this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($object);
echo '</pre>';
```

This should work for arrays or objects.

Also, I believe objects in PHP 5 have a "to_array" magic method that can convert an Object to an array of data.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output for debugging purpose, you could use [print_r](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [var_dump](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) which is more verbose about your object.